# Switching from AWS com to software for route53 , what method can I use to make similar use like shutdown() method found in com package

Tags: amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-route53

I have switched from using com packages to software packages to access route53. I am handling client objects in a list. I am using shutdown() method from com.amazonaws.services.route53 to shutdown my client objects. Now that I have switched to software.amazon.awssdk.services.route53, I am not able to find any method similar that I can use to shutdown the client objects in the list. Any help would be useful, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the AWS V2 you can call `close()` to do something similar to the V1 `shutdown()`.  However, all new clients implement [AutoClosable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html?is-external=true) so your code can look something like:

```
try( Route53Client r53client = Route53Client.create() ) {
    // do what you need
}
```

Comment: I am iterating through a list of clients and I close each client in the loop hence closing all the clients. Why should I create a new client in a try block then?

Comment: You don't have to in that case.  It is just one more way of doing it if your code fits.  The `close()` method works fine too.